# Есть столбец text , но искать надо только внутри конкретного тега

Tags: mysql

В этом столбце есть текстовое описание, какое угодное....
и есть некий текст, обрамленный словом "code_" и начинается с новой строки , например
В лесу родилась елочка ...
code_ Солнышко ясное колоколышко code_

Что надо сделать , чтобы искать внутри этого code_ code_
неважно, подстрока или...

Comment: с помощью регулярных выражений http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Regexp.html хотя лучше конечно было бы воспользоваться полнотекстовым поиском и возможно не средствами MySQL

Comment: хотя обычный like то же вполне сгодиться `like '%code\_%code\_%`

Comment: c помощью сфинкса возможно это сделать?  и как?

Comment: то есть чтоб регистр не учитывался?